# How to set NSLocalNotification to run on monthly or weekly basis for the same time scheduled?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have my app with data coming from server. I have 2 type of notifications say monthly. Now I will get data say for month with (date-time format) 2-2:30,6-9:00,23-10:00,26-12:00. where 2 denotes date followed by time with colon (:) format.

Now I want to run the notification every month on the same dates and time. I am able to run the multiple notifications. But they do not repeat every month. How to do that? Following is my code for the same.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
          [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
            UIUserNotificationSettings *notiSett = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:NULL];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerUserNotificationSettings:notiSett];
                    [self generateLocalNotificationDaily];
    }

   -(void)generateLocalNotificationDaily
{
//  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [self compareDateDaily];
}

-(void)compareDateDaily
{
    NSString *strTime = [Helper getPREF:PREF_AlARM_DAILY_TIME];
    NSArray *arrtime = [strTime componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    for(int i=0;i<[arrtime count];i++)
    {
        NSArray *arrfirstTime = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrtime objectAtIndex:i]]componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

        int hh = (int)[[arrfirstTime objectAtIndex:0]integerValue];
        int mm = (int)[[arrfirstTime objectAtIndex:1]integerValue];

        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 1;//24 * 60 * 60;
        NSDate *date = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsPerDay];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
        [components setHour:hh];
        [components setMinute:mm];
        NSDate *todaySpecificDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSString *strCurrentDate = [formatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
        NSString *strSystemDate = [formatter stringFromDate:todaySpecificDate];
        currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:strCurrentDate];
        todaySpecificDate = [formatter dateFromString:strSystemDate];

        NSComparisonResult result = [currentDate compare:todaySpecificDate];

        NSString *strAlertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Helper getPREF:PREF_AlARM_MESSAGE]];
        NSString *strUserName = [Helper getPREF:PREF_NAME];
        NSString *strmsg = [strAlertMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"user_name" withString:strUserName];
        NSString *alertMsg = [strmsg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"notification_type" withString:@"daily"];

        //
        switch (result)
        {
            case NSOrderedAscending:
            {
                UILocalNotification* localNotificationDaily = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                localNotificationDaily.fireDate = todaySpecificDate;
                localNotificationDaily.alertBody = alertMsg;
                localNotificationDaily.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

                localNotificationDaily.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotificationDaily];
                NSLog(@"%@ is in future from %@", todaySpecificDate, currentDate);
            }
                break;
            case NSOrderedDescending:
                NSLog(@"%@ is in past from %@", todaySpecificDate, currentDate);
                break;
            case NSOrderedSame:
                NSLog(@"%@ is the same as %@", todaySpecificDate, currentDate);
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", todaySpecificDate, currentDate);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a property in uiLocalNotification "repeatInterval". You have to set the repeat interval to month like this

```
localNotificationMonthly.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMonth;
```

It will repeat your notification every month depending upon the date and time you set for the notification. For further inquiry please refer to

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval

for week repeat interval would be NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear

Comment: I tried with daily notification localNotificationDaily.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay; and tested on my simulator with today and changing date to 12th July. It did not work :(

Comment: it should be NSCalendarUnitMonth as you want to repeat monthly.

Comment: Yes but I want for daily too and that too does not work..!!

Comment: is your date is created properly?

Comment: plz check my code. I edited it to daily. and it works for "today" but if I change my date to 12th July i.e. tomorrow, it does not show notifications in simulator.

Comment: can you gave me a proper date string?So i can run i

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116986/discussion-between-sarah-and-muhammad-zohaib-ehsan).